# Stripe: 'payment_intent.succeeded' is also triggered when subscription gets renewed

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have two APIs for Stripe webhooks in my backend (Django).

- "Subscription" webhook: `/api/subscriptions/webhook/`
- "Add Balance to Wallet" webhook: `/api/wallet/webhook/`

In the subscription webhook, I listen for `invoice.paid` and `invoice.payment_failed` events and in the wallet webhook I listen for `payment_intent.succeeded` event. The problem is whenever the subscription webhook gets called, the `payment_intent.succeeded` event is also triggered for the wallet webhook. I think that's because payment intents are also created for subscription as well. I need a way to differentiate these two (one-time payment [aka add balance to wallet] and subscription) so I don't end up with extra credit in user's wallet whenever their subscription get renewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the `invoice.paid` event for both webhooks and check the `data.object.lines.data[0].price.type` field which can be either `one_time` or `recurring`. You can read more about it at https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/line_item#invoice_line_item_object-type

Comment: I'm having the same issue, however I don't see that successfully charging a one_time payment triggers the invoice.paid webhook event. Does this still work?